# Adding numbers to each line error

Tags: java

I want to add numbers to each line of the txt that my code reads but this error shows up:

> LineNumbers.java:32: lineNum is already defined in main(java.lang.String[])
>
> for(int lineNum = 0; lineNum <= line; lineNum++)
>
> LineNumbers.java:32: operator <= cannot be applied to int,java.lang.String
>
> for(int lineNum = 0; lineNum <= line; lineNum++)

my code is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class LineNumbers
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      String fileName;
      String line;
      int lineNum = 0;

      System.out.print("Enter file name: ");
      fileName = keyboard.nextLine();

      File file = new File(fileName);
      Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

      while (inputFile.hasNextLine())
      {
            line = inputFile.nextLine();
         for(int lineNum = 0; lineNum <= line; lineNum++)
         {
            System.out.println(line);
         }
      }

      inputFile.close();
   }
}
```

Any help would very much appreciated. thanks for your time!

Comment: The error's pretty self-explanatory: You're asking whether the line number is less than the line of text, which makes no sense whatsoever. What's the `for` loop supposed to be doing?

Comment: Why are you redefining `int lineNum`?

Comment: the loop should add 1, 2, 3, 4, etc for each line of txt it reads.
@chrylis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will make sense.

```
  while (inputFile.hasNextLine())
  {
        line = inputFile.nextLine();
        lineNum++;
        System.out.println("Line Number:"+lineNum+" = "+line);

  }
  System.out.println(lineNum);
```

Comment: Except this only prints the total after all the lines have been read.

Comment: thnx  @Java Devil.. updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Change your loop to this :

```
while ((line = inputFile.nextLine())!=null)
  {
       System.out.println(line+":"+lineNum++);

  }
```

You are getting error because you already defined lineNum at the starting and you are declaring it again in for loop. 
Second thing, you can't compare `int` with `String` value. It cause the second error that you are facing.

Comment: `line` is a `String`, so **the inequality does not make sense**

Comment: @Barranka When you were commenting, I was updating my answer :)